# Updating vulnerable packages within "packages-lock.json" through the command line

Tags: javascript, angular, github, npm, package-lock.json

The code for my app is managed through GitHub and GitHub is telling me there are some vulnerabilities within my **package-lock.json** file. [image]

Now as I understand it is that there could be multiple packages within the **package.json** file that depend or use these vulnerable packages within the **package-lock.json** file.

How do I update these packages to secure versions through the command line.

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried running `npm install`
2. I have tried removing the package-lock.json file and running `npm install`
3. I have also tried `npm update` & then `npm install`.

Comment: Maybe you can't do anything, if they are already up to date and the vulnerabily is on the lastest version

Comment: @jonatjano Hi,Thanks for the comment. They are not latest version, GitHub is telling which version I need update to but none of the commands I have tried is updating them.

Comment: can you add your `package.json` please (or the part with these package if it is too long)